# merge two lists to make list of lists

Tags: python, arrays, list

I want to merge the 2 lists:

```
a = [1,2,3,4,"a"]
b = [1,2,3,4,"b"]
```

to make:

```
[[1,1], [2,2], [3,3], [4,4], ["a","b"]]
```

What would be the best way of doing this?

Also if possible I would like to append further lists as well like so:

```
c = [5,6,7,8,"c"]
```

to get

```
[[1,1,5], [2,2,6], [3,3,7], [4,4,8], [5,5,9], ["a","b","c"]
```

You can assume the lists are the same length.

Comment: yes i realise it maybe a duplicate question but i did not find anything by searching

Comment: He's not asking for a list of tuples, but a list of lists

Comment: why people frenetically downvote such a question ?

Comment: I could probably use tuples instead as the data is immutable after this point. final goal is to get json output from 500+ lists with 100+ variables in each, with a separate dict prepended to each list inside each list.

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent https://www.google.co.in/search?q=merge+two+list+into+list+of+lists+python First hit, and converting a tuple to list is very trivial.

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent You might even argue that the list element is different from the referenced question.

Comment: okay, i realise it is a bit of a newbie question now. thanks everybody for your time.

Comment: @Aशwiniचhaudhary Ok, but the score attained -3 when I wrote my comment (that's what I call "frenetic"), and none explanation in the comments. Personnally I never downvote a question already having a negative score, except if it is really a piss-take. This is just my personal opinion.

Comment: @devnull I don't understand what you say (my English). I have re-read the  other topic, for me this is not the same question. *"Converting a tuple to list is very trivial"* is true for someone who has a minimal knowledge in Python. Is it forbidden to be a beginner ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) and a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
>>> a = [1, 2, 3, 4, "a"]
>>> b = [1, 2, 3, 4, "b"]
>>> new_lst = [list(x) for x in zip(a, b)]
>>> new_lst
[[1, 1], [2, 2], [3, 3], [4, 4], ['a', 'b']]
>>>
```

---

**Edit:**

Regarding your updated question, if you later want to add in another list, you can use this:

```
>>> c = [5, 6, 7, 8, "c"]
>>> [x + [y] for x,y in zip(new_lst, c)]
[[1, 1, 5], [2, 2, 6], [3, 3, 7], [4, 4, 8], ['a', 'b', 'c']]
>>>
```

Of course, if you have all three lists to begin with, all you need to do is give another argument to `zip`:

```
>>> a = [1, 2, 3, 4, "a"]
>>> b = [1, 2, 3, 4, "b"]
>>> c = [5, 6, 7, 8, "c"]
>>> new_lst = [list(x) for x in zip(a, b, c)]
>>> new_lst
[[1, 1, 5], [2, 2, 6], [3, 3, 7], [4, 4, 8], ['a', 'b', 'c']]
>>>
```

Comment: thanks, i will delete the question now as it is a duplicate.

Comment: it is not exactly a duplicate, @Dave

Comment: thanks - and for answering my edited update as well. i understand it much better now.

Answer (score 1):

## Variation of accepted solution

As it is explicitly declaring items for sublist, it seems to me a bit more readable:

```
>>> a = [1,2,3,4,"a"]
>>> b = [1,2,3,4,"b"]
>>> c = [5,6,7,8,"c"]
>>> [[ai, bi, ci] for ai, bi, ci in zip(a, b, c)]
[[1, 1, 5], [2, 2, 6], [3, 3, 7], [4, 4, 8], ['a', 'b', 'c']]
```

## Shortes variant using `map`

```
>>> map(list, zip(a, b, c))
[[1, 1, 5], [2, 2, 6], [3, 3, 7], [4, 4, 8], ['a', 'b', 'c']]
```